# How to access two file from argv

Tags: c

I want to make a program that reads a file destination from cmd line. That should happen twice because i want to use two files. Therefore i used argv as a parameter in main. The code is the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>

main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
FILE *fp1, *fp2;
int array1[5][5];
int array2[5][5];
int i, j;

fp1 = fopen(argv[1], "w");
fp2 = fopen(argv[2], "w");

for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    for (j = 0; j <5; j++)
    {
        scanf("%d", array1[i][j]);
        scanf("%d", array2[i][j]);
    }
}

fprintf(fp1, "%d", array1);
fprintf(fp2, "%d", array2);
}
```

The run log is the following:

```
--------------------------------
Process exited after 2.263 seconds with return value 3221225477
Press any key to continue . . .
```

It compiles ok but when i run the executable it won't let me input anything and it just exits after 2 seconds. Why is that?

Comment: Please show your exact run log.

Comment: `scanf("%d", array1[i][j]);` -> `scanf("%d", &array1[i][j]);`

Comment: `fprintf(fp1, "%d", array1);` You can't print the whole array with a single `fprintf` like that. Need to loop over the arrays as you have already done with the `for` loops.

Comment: Did you check the compiler warnings?

Comment: @4386427 no warnings whatsoever

Comment: Not in comments. Please [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/65991640/edit) the question with the exact command you used to run the program and the resulting log.

Comment: @Kos - then you really need to enable warnings - you should get a number of warnings - how do you compile the program?

Comment: What is your platform? How do you invoke the program? You don't check if ? `fopen` fails. You don't check if `argv` is greater than 2.

Comment: @4386427 i use devcpp

Comment: What exactly do you type as input?

Comment: ... and it should be `scanf("%d", &array1[i][j]);`

Comment: @4386427 i cannot type anything

Comment: What do you mean by - "cannot type anything"? Don't you get a terminal window?

Comment: @4386427 i do get a terminal window i just cannot type anything. No character that i strike on the keyboard shows in the terminal and it just exits by itself.

Comment: strange... did you fix the `scanf` bug?

Comment: @4386427 yes i did.

Comment: Do basic debugging. Use a debugger to step thru the code line by line. Or even just add basic debug print statements to verify you are running what you think you are and to see how far the program gets. And you still haven't told us how you run the program - what is the exact command line?

Comment: @Jabberwocky i added an `if (argc > 2)` check and now i am able to write to the terminal. But when i input the file path it just exits.

Comment: @Kos also add the error checks for `fopen` and what I suggested in my previous comment. And then [edit] the question with the new code.

Comment: @Kos andwhat do you think  `fprintf(fp1, "%d", array1)` does?

Comment: Arguments in argv go on the command line that executes the program.

Comment: If you want to run  a program in an IDE with arguments, commonly you need to specify the arguments in some kind of a "run configuration". You cannot specify them in an input window, which usually provides `stdin` and `stdout`. -- Some IDEs have a terminal view, but that is different. You recognize it by the prompt. In this terminal view, you will call your program with the arguments on one line.